# Adding animation to 3D models in ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

In this video an object is given an animation to hover around the room when placed and then when tapped it gets dropped down with another animation.
How can I add this kind of animations in my project?
Is adding an already animated object the only way?

Thank you

https://youtu.be/OS_kScr0XkQ

Comment: Speaking for myself, I'm reluctant to follow any [random YouTube video](https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ) as it could be anything. Describe what you want - leave the link in for reference, but don't force us to watch a video. Help us to help you.

Comment: The question heading refers to what am I trying to do. And the video is just a sample of what I want to do.

Comment: There is no animation in that video where th objects “hovers around the room”. It hovers up and down, the movement sideways is not animated. Many properties of SceneKit objects can be animated as described in the docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/animation/animating_scenekit_content In your case you could use a SCNAction as well, similar to the one in the default SceneKit Game template in Xcode.

Answer (score 12):

I think the hovering up and down is most likely an animation sequence. The following animation sequence for a hovering effect will work inside the first drop down selection function.

```
        let moveDown = SCNAction.move(by: SCNVector3(0, -0.1, 0), duration: 1)
        let moveUp = SCNAction.move(by: SCNVector3(0,0.1,0), duration: 1)
        let waitAction = SCNAction.wait(duration: 0.25)
        let hoverSequence = SCNAction.sequence([moveUp,waitAction,moveDown])
        let loopSequence = SCNAction.repeatForever(hoverSequence)
        node2Animate.runAction(loopSequence)

        self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node2Animate)
```

The second part to stop the animation when you tap the node put this inside the tap gesture function.

```
node2animate.removeAllActions()
```

The last part dropping to the floor, the node2animate might be a physicsBody and before the tap the gravity attribute

```
node2animate.physicsBody?.isAffectedByGravity = false
```

after the tap you set it to true

```
node2animate.physicsBody?.isAffectedByGravity = true
```

There is other stuff going on as well, collision with the floor have also been set etc.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Hey @Clay any idea on how to add gravity/collision once the animation stop? I mean to reset the position of the object to the flor

Comment: These days I’m using Reality Composer to build interactive AR scenes without code that can be viewed in the browser via AR Quick Look or RealityKit apps. Its better to build AR scenes that are code independent. Check out usdzshare.com for AR via the browser.