# How to make animation in ARkit by changing position per second

Tags: arkit

I what to make animation in ARkit to a SCNnode by changing its positions, kind of like a render loop. Means to change the location 60 time per second, how can I do that?

Comment: Hi, please provide some example of what you have been developed to help people understand your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to change your node's position 60 times a second, then you could just implement the renderer 'updateAtTime' function for the 'ARSCNViewDelegate'.
That function should be called at around 60 times a second.

A dumb version might be

```
extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate, ARSessionDelegate {
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
        yourNode.simdWorldPosition.z -= 0.01
    }
```

That would move the previously defined `yourNode` 1 cm in the -Z direction 60 times a second. You could write this with an iteration tracker to loop whatever position actions you want.

You could also do an actual animation with something like

```
    let startingZ = node.simdWorldPosition.z
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "simdWorldPosition.z")
    animation.fromValue = startingZ
    animation.toValue = startingZ - 2.0
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.autoreverses = true
    animation.repeatCount = .infinity
    yourNode.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "backAndForth")
```

Or you could use SCNActions as shown here: [Adding animation to 3D models in ARKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48597130/adding-animation-to-3d-models-in-arkit)

Comment: Awesome! Glad to be helpful. If you're question is answered, would you mind awarding me the answer and giving an up arrow?

Comment: @jfriesenhahn i have posted a question here: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59005938/how-to-remain-the-arimageanchor-video-play-on-screen-after-camera-leave-the-trac". Can you help me on animating an ARImageAnchor on the user screen?